# terraform collaboration with one state file

Tags: terraform

I'm struggling to solve a problem with terraform :
The problem in short is related to collaboration between teams while writing infra code using the SAME state file exemple :

- Infra team :  network plumbing
- App team: create VMs/k8s workloads

App team obviously takes some inputs from the infra team using data sources... until here everything is alright. Both teams use different git repos but same remote STATE file.

Because both teams uses the SAME state file, ressources created by one team ( example  infra team) are marked for DELETION when App team tries to deploy something and vice versa.

can we prevent this, is using separate state files  the only solution ?
thanks you

Comment: Two root configs should not share a single state. It will be tedious to split out the state to each of the root configs, but it will solve your problem as well as other future problems.

Comment: understood, I was under the impression that terraforn uses one state file to represent the entire infra fro the config files

Comment: States are a one-to-one mapping to and from each root config workspace. So, your number of states would be the total number of workspaces in each root config added together.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is Yes.
Separate state files is the best long-term solution. The other option that you could think about is workspaces but according to terraform documentation that's not a good idea:

> When Terraform is used to manage larger systems, teams should use multiple separate Terraform configurations that correspond with suitable architectural boundaries within the system so that different components can be managed separately and, if appropriate, by distinct teams. Workspaces alone are not a suitable tool for system decomposition, because each subsystem should have its own separate configuration and backend, and will thus have its own distinct set of workspaces.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html#when-to-use-multiple-workspaces